# @RequestScoped in Quarkus having same hashcode for all request bean

Tags: spring, quarkus

I have used @RequestScoped with quarkus framework. My requirement is for every request new object must be created. But Whenever I have checked the hashcode for all bean for all request then it was same. Means as per my understanding if the first request is there it will create one bean which having some hashcode ,whenever second request will come it will create another bean with different hashcode .But in reality it was same hashcode. Can any one help me to know reason behind it ?

Answer (score 4):

`@RequestScoped` beans, as well as all other normal-scoped beans, are not injected directly. Instead, a so called *client proxy* is injected. This client proxy, on each method invocation, looks up the correct instance (in this case, an instance belonging to the "current" request) and forwards the method invocation to it.

So, what you're observing is totally expected. There's *one* instance of the client proxy, but that doesn't mean there is not a dedicated instance for each request.

There's one twist to it. I said that all methods are forwarded to the correct instance, so you might expect that hash codes would be different for different requests. That isn't the case, though, because the CDI spec says:

> The behavior of all methods declared by java.lang.Object, except for toString(), is undefined for a client proxy. Portable applications should not invoke any method declared by java.lang.Object, except for toString(), on a client proxy.

So no, hash codes don't have to be different. If you really want to prove that each request gets a different instance, generate a unique ID in the constructor of the bean class, and expose it though some method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will try by generating unique id.

Answer (score 0):

If a bean class has the annotation @RequestScoped, CDI will lazily instantiate the bean during the first call to a bean method. Such a bean lives only within a chain used to process a single HTTP request.

Follow this link for more information->[@RequestScoped](https://marcelkliemannel.com/articles/2021/overview-of-bean-scopes-in-quarkus/#:%7E:text=If%20a%20bean%20class%20has%20the%20annotation%20%40RequestScoped%20%2C%20CDI%20will,process%20a%20single%20HTTP%20request.)